# What do the difficulty settings change in Freedom Planet?

Tags: freedom-planet

In Freedom Planet, there are four difficulty settings. What changes between difficulty settings?

For example, do harder difficulties:

- Have more enemies?
- Have enemies do more damage when they hit you?
- Have enemies take more hits before dying?
- Change the locations of items within levels?
- Use different level layouts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differences go as such:

- On Casual, you receive only half of the normal damage from enemies and you also have passive health regeneration 1 unit/sec. You essentially cannot die unless you actively try.
- On Easy, you receive normal amount of damage but you have passive 0.5/sec health regeneration. Ideal for more laid-back platforming experience
- On Normal, normal damage and no health regeneration. For those experienced with classic platformers like 2D Sonic or Mega Man games.
- On Hard, you receive double the normal damage, your shields only hold one attack, instead of two (except for Milla), you need to collect 300 crystals for 1UP (instead of 200) AND some of the bosses are faster/have randomized attack patterns. Hardcore only.